# How can I get the package name of the current launcher in android 2.3 and above?

Tags: java, android, launcher

How can I get the package name of the current launcher in android 2.3 and above programmatically in Java ?

Comment: Doesn't that only give the package name of the current app ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I think you should be able to use [PackageManager.resolveActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#resolveActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29), with the home intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
String currentHomePackage = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
```

Comment: If there is no selected "default" launcher it returns just "android". Not a common case, but it happens.

Comment: Be aware that it will return NULL if there is no match and you will get a NPE at the last line!

Comment: Yes, this is illustratory code to illustrate the solution, and should not be used as-is for "production" use. Besides, if your phone doesn't have a home application... you probably have other problems :)

Comment: For anyone wanting to run the block of code in this answer on an Android 11+ device, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69801531/1071320) about Android 11 package visibility changes which you should take into account.

Answer (score 3):

With the [package visibility changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility) introduced in Android 11, it is now necessary to add a [queries](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element) element in your application's manifest file as below before you can query the [PackageManager.resolveActivity(intent:flags:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#resolveActivity(android.content.Intent,%20int)) method for the default home (a.k.a. launcher) activity that is installed on the device:

```xml
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

If this [queries](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element) element is omitted from your application's manifest, then the device will report the `com.android.settings.FallbackHome` activity as its default home activity and that is most likely not what you want.

For guidance on how to query the [PackageManager.resolveActivity(intent:flags:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#resolveActivity(android.content.Intent,%20int)) method, see the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10344985/1071320) in this thread.

Answer (score -2):

in general, [I agree to @JesusFreke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10344985/529977) using the PM resolveActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

but to get the right package name, you should use

```
resolveInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString()
```

or

```
resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString()
```

---

Hint:
if there is no default set, this might become "Android System" or "open" as for the general System Intent Receiver

Hint:
if you're looking for web browsers, you might use `net.openid.appauth.browser.BrowserSelector#select()` ([0.7.1+](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/blob/0.7.1/library/java/net/openid/appauth/browser/BrowserSelector.java#L151)) to implicit get the default browser even there is no one explicit set.

Comment: That's the human readable name of the application, not the package name.