# How to determine if the foreground app is the launcher?

Tags: android, launcher

I know how to retrieve information about the foreground app:

```
public ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo getForegroundTask()
{
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService( Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    return am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0);
}

public String getForegroundTaskPackageName()
{
    return getForegroundTask().topActivity.getPackageName();
}
```

My question is, how can I know for sure that the foreground app is the launcher? I can't rely on the package name as it could be anything, like "com.android.launcher" or "com.htc.launcher".

Thanks

Comment: By combining your code above with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344824/how-can-i-get-the-package-name-of-the-current-launcher-in-android-2-3-and-above ?

Comment: That is absolutely right. I swear I searched before asking :) Thanks.

Comment: ;) And I swear I didn't appreciate SO automatically considering my answer _trivial_ and turining it into a comment, so I wrote an answer again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to combine your code snippet to determine the package name of the foreground process with a call to `PackageManager` to get information about the HOME activity, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344824/how-can-i-get-the-package-name-of-the-current-launcher-in-android-2-3-and-above), and compare the results.