# How to Show Device's Home Launcher from my own Launcher

Tags: android, android-launcher

I am writing an app in which i have to show device's Home Launcher when user do click on button (which i have placed on my own launcher), I tried using this code, but its showing all the apps installed on my device, but what if i want to show Device's Home Launcher only on button click

```
public class DefaultLaunchActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);
        btnDeviceLauncher = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnDeviceLauncher.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(startMain);
            }
        });
     }
}
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.def.launc.DefaultLaunchActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:stateNotNeeded="true"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>         
</activity>
```

Comment: u found solution can u pls tell me i also have same issues failed to show home screen of device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a launcher application is also launched by an `Intent`. So if you write your own launcher application and set that application as your default launcher application, the next time there is an `Intent` for the launcher application, **your own application is going to be launched**, not the previous launcher because the `Intent` is for the launcher application and your application *is* the launcher application right now.

So if you want the original launcher application to be launched from inside your launcher (although I don't think it will look the same as when it was actually the launcher) you will have to launch it manually using the package name as described here: [start application knowing package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422758/start-application-knowing-package-name).

To get the package name of the actual launcher application refer: [How can I get the package name of the current launcher in android 2.3 and above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344824/how-can-i-get-the-package-name-of-the-current-launcher-in-android-2-3-and-above)